# Явные отличия CMP от TEST

Tags: ассемблер

Я начал изучать устройство одной программы недавно, целиком написанной на ассемблере (т.е никакие трансляторы в машинный не применялись, как в языках высокого уровня). Так вот, в ней я очень часто встречаю конструкции вида `TEST AL, AL` ; `TEST EAX, EAX` и т.д.

Вот вопрос: почему применяется `TEST`, а не `CMP`? Да и какой смысл сравниваться с самим собой? Насколько я знаю, `TEST` использует логическое "И" (`AND`). Проясните, пожалуйста, в этих деталях я не особо просвещён.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Команды вида `test reg, reg` используется для сравнения значения регистра с нулем. После этой операции флаги нуля, знака и чётности либо устанавливаются, либо сбрасываются. Почему не `cmp reg, 0`? Потому что в скомпилированном виде `test reg, reg` на целый байт короче, ну и по скорости наверное разница есть.

`test` эквивалентен побитовому `and`, за исключением того, что модифицируются только флаги, но не операнды. Обычно это нужно, чтобы узнать, установлены ли определенные биты в регистре.

А `cmp` эквивалентен обыкновенному вычитанию, но аналогично модифицирует флаги, не изменяя операнды.

Answer (score 8):

```
CMP  Reg1, Reg2 l =2 байта, t = 3 такта, спаривается в любом конвеере
TEST Reg1, Reg2 l =2 байта, t = 3 такта, спаривается в любом конвеере

CMP  Reg, Const l = 3-4 байта t = 4 такта, спаривается в любом конвеере
```

Разница в количестве используемых регистров, в результате оптимизации кода и наборе изменяющихся флагов.Т.к. обычно используется следующий формат: TEST Reg1, Reg1, ну и соответственно логике - TEST сравнение с 0 :)

Answer (score 5):

Установление флагов после этой короткой инструкции test ax,ax **85C0** , позволяет с легкостью не только читать код, благодаря простоте вида , но и уменьшить процессорные временные затраты (реализация AND (логическое "И") - проще сумматора, на нём резализованного, когда используется CMP (вычитание).
В подавляющем большинстве случаев, после проверки на 0 используются команды условного перехода Jcc (в данном случае JE (equal) переход если равны (ZF=1)).

```
   mov  ax, 0 
   test ax, ax                  ; and 0 with 0 
   je   flag_not_set    ; always taken 
   mov  ax, 1 
   test ax, ax                  ; and 1 with 1 
   je   flag_not_set    ; not taken
```

Вот схематика на уровне микроинструкций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]