# Убрать защиту от дебаггера

Tags: ассемблер, отладка, дизассемблирование

```
.text:00401870 ; Attributes: noreturn bp-based frame
.text:00401870
.text:00401870 _wmain          proc near               ; CODE XREF: ___tmainCRTStartup+10A↑p
.text:00401870                 push    ebp
.text:00401871                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00401873                 call    ds:IsDebuggerPresent
.text:00401879                 test    eax, eax
.text:0040187B                 jz      short loc_401884
.text:0040187D                 call    sub_401730
.text:00401882 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00401882                 jmp     short loc_401889
.text:00401884 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00401884
.text:00401884 loc_401884:                             ; CODE XREF: _wmain+B↑j
.text:00401884                 call    sub_4017B0
.text:00401889 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00401889
.text:00401889 loc_401889:                             ; CODE XREF: _wmain+12↑j
.text:00401889                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0040188B                 pop     ebp
.text:0040188C                 retn
.text:0040188C _wmain          endp
.text:0040188C
.text:0040188C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Что здесь отвечает за проверку на проверку от отладки ?

Comment: А вам строка "IsDebuggerPresent" ни о чем не говорит ?

Comment: @Mike, честно - нет , поэтому сюда и написал

Comment: в google translate эту фразу забейте, только через пробел. Хотя imho тут даже знания английского не надо, что бы догадаться что может значить эта фраза

Comment: @Mike, типо есть ли отладчик

Comment: @Mike, меня интересует jz short , что она делает , после проверки наличия отладчика

Comment: Ну а больше сказать и нечего, по следующей команде видно, что содержимое eax проверяют на 0. Значит можно предположить, что функция в eax возвращает как раз 0 или 1. А вот какое значение о чем говорит из кода совершенно не ясно. Я бы остерегся предполагать, что 0 говорит об отсутствии (хотя исходя из названия функции вроде как 1 должна означать присутствие). jz производит переход если протестированное значение равно нулю

Comment: @Elvin, полезно читать документацию. Просто вбиваете название функции в поисковик, находите что функция делает, какие значения возвращает. Дальше, по ассемблеру желательно почитать про регистр флагов, про то как арифметические и логические операции влияют на регистр флагов, про условные переходы. Ну и про соглашения вызова тоже. Это на один вечер почитать, дальше все станет намного понятнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция WinAPI [IsDebuggerPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) определяет запущена ли программа под отладчиком или нет. Если под отладчиком, из функции возвращается "не ноль", если не под отладчиком - ноль.

В условном языке высокого уровня это например означает что после вызова:

```
r = IsDebuggerPresent()
```

в переменной `r` будет 0, если программа запущена не под отладчиком, и что-то другое, если нет.

В машинном коде все по-другому. Здесь применяются низкоуровневые правила обмена данными, в том числе между кодом и вызываемыми функциями ([Application binary interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), ABI). В разных операционных системах эти правила различаются.

Для 32-битного кода под Windows при обращении к функция WinAPI применяются соглашения stdcall и cdecl (см. [Соглашения о вызове](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85,_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_x86_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_32-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) в Википедии). Если вкратце, то параметры в функции передаются через стек (`push` перед вызовом функции через `call`), возвращаемое значение возвращается через регистр `eax`. `stdcall` и `cdecl` различаются только тем, кто выравнивает указатель стека на размер переданных в функцию параметров после окончания работы функции - сама функция или вызывающий код. В данном случае это не существенно, т.к. у функции `IsDebuggerPresent` вообще нет параметров.

Теперь смотрим снова на ваш код. После вызова функции `IsDebuggerPresent` проверяется значение в регистре `eax`. Для этого выполняется команда `test eax, eax`. По сути это побитовое сравнение числа самого с собой. На первый взгляд это не имеет смысла, но на самом деле, если в `eax` лежал ноль, то после операции `test` в регистре флагов устанавливается (становится 1) бит ZF, который как бы говорит, что результат последней операции был нулём. См. вопрос [Явные отличия CMP от TEST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/135230/1365)
. См. также [Регистр флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2) в Википедии.

Дальше идет команда `jz short loc_401884`. Это команда условного перехода, т.е. переход по определенному адресу, если выполняется какое-то условие. В данном случае переход по адресу метки `loc_401884` происходит, если в регистре флагов установлен бит ZF.

Таким образом, если программа запущена **не** под отладчиком, то в процессе исполнения кода произойдет переход по метке `loc_401884`. Если под отладчиком, переход не произойдет, дальше выполнится команда `jmp short loc_401889`, произойдет переход по метке `loc_401889`.

Как избавиться от проверки? Несколько вариантов:

1. Убрать вызов функции `IsDebuggerPresent`, вместо него записать в регистр `eax` 0. Или заменить на вызов какой-то функции, которая гарантированно вернет 0 (хотя это уже излишнее усложнение).
2. Заменить `test eax, eax` на операцию, результатом которой будет ноль. Например `xor eax, eax` (результат всегда будет 0, в регистр `eax` запишется 0).
3. Заменить условный переход `jz short loc_401884` на безусловный `jmp short loc_401884`, чтобы вне зависимости от результата вызова функции `IsDebuggerPresent` всегда происходил переход на ветку кода, которая обрабатывает вариант, когда программа запущена не под отладчиком.