# объясните test eax, eax и jg

Tags: ассемблер

в `eax` помещается число, например `20`. потом такое выражение.

```
test eax, eax
jg short loc_xxx
```

`jg` в данном случае означает, что будет переход, если число больше нуля?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Явные отличия CMP от TEST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/135230/1365)

Answer (score 1):

**Команда TEST** выполняет логическое И между всеми битами двух операндов.

В зависимости от результата могут быть изменены флаги ZF, SF, PF.

- set ZF, если 0
- set SF, если отрицательный
- set PF, если устанавливается четное количество бит

Инструкция TEST всегда сбрасывает флаги OF и CF.

**Инструкция JG** проверяет флаги ZF, SF и OF. Переход выполняется, если

- ZF = 0
- SF = OF

**Таким образом** `test eax, eax` по сути производит сравнение eax с нулём. Устанавливает ZF, если `eax == 0`

Comment: Не помешал бы еще вывод, при каких значениях eax переход выполняется или не выполняется. Из простого описания команд это не очевидно.