# Какая конструкция отработает быстрее: if (a == 0 || b == 0) или if (a*b == 0)?

Tags: c++

Какая конструкция отработает быстрее:

```
if (a == 0 || b == 0)
```

или

```
if (a*b == 0)
```

Comment: лучше определите, что чаще будет вылетать в 0 - а или б? И выставьте вперед ту что чаще.

Comment: Вы только не забывайте, что это не  эквивалентные условия. Даже если оба операнда ненулевые, их произведение всё равно может быть нулевым.

Comment: или `if(!(a&b))`

Comment: Каких типов `a` и `b`? Это может быть очень важно.

Comment: А еще интересно сравнить с `if(~(a&&b))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А давайте протестируем. Тестовый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

enum class func_method {log_or, mult};

template <typename test_type, func_method method>
void test_func()
{
    const unsigned long end = 4000000000;

    volatile test_type x = 1;
    volatile test_type y = 1;
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    auto clock_begin = std::clock();
    if (method == func_method::log_or)
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < end; ++i)
        {
            test_type a = x;
            test_type b = y;
            if (a == 0 || b == 0)
                ++sum;
        }
    else if (method == func_method::mult)
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < end; ++i)
        {
            test_type a = x;
            test_type b = y;
            if (a * b == 0)
                ++sum;
        }
    else
        cout << "Invalid method" << endl;
    auto clock_end = std::clock();

    cout << "sum:  " << sum << endl;
    cout << "time: " << double(clock_end - clock_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}

int main()
{
    typedef int test_type;
      
    test_func<test_type, func_method::mult>();
    test_func<test_type, func_method::log_or>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com (ссылки на примеры: [int](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2519821ff6ec23f), [unsigned int](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae50e8081fc9a890), [long long](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dcc9676a8ca9730), [double](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5ca98fb98027a30)), g++, количество итераций — `4'000'000'000`, `a == 1; b == 1`, время в секундах:

```
test_type:    int         unsigned int         long long         double
умножение:    3.38705     3.47416              5.2172            5.07862
или:          4.98977     4.89922              4.95778           8.35183
```

Проверка с помощью умножения работает быстрее, чем проверка с помощью логического или, кроме типа `long long`.

---

https://ideone.com (ссылки на примеры: [int](https://ideone.com/kQLm1c), [unsigned int](https://ideone.com/DVZa7y), [long long](https://ideone.com/s7wodO), [double](https://ideone.com/AeB4T0)), clang 8.0, количество итераций — `2'000'000'000`, `a == 0; b == 1`, время в секундах:

```
test_type:    int         unsigned int         long long         double
умножение:    0.996721    0.931937             0.918067          1.55657
или:          1.73786     1.69223              1.93048           2.8409
```

На ideone.com с использованием clang проверка с помощью умножения также стабильно опережает проверку с помощью логического или (даже при использовании типа `long long`, даже при переменной `a` равной нулю, т.е. не нужно проверять вторую часть условия `b == 0`)

---

Но это были примеры с фиксированными значениями переменных `a` и `b`. @avp заметил в комментариях, что время работы умножителя может зависеть от чисел, и предложил протестировать на случайных значениях.

Напишем небольшую вспомогательную функцию для генерации псевдослучайных чисел на основе [линейного конгруэнтного метода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4):

```
std::uint32_t rand_value;

std::uint32_t lcg()
{
    const auto a = 22695477u;
    const auto c = 1u;

    rand_value = a * rand_value + c;
    return rand_value;
}
```

Если `test_type` есть `unsigned int`, `long long` или `double`, то переменные `a` и `b` будем инициализировать так:

```
test_type a = lcg();
test_type b = lcg();
```

Если `test_type` есть 32-битный `int`, то `a` и `b` будем инициализировать так (чтобы избежать переполнения при вычислении произведения):

```
test_type a = lcg() & 32767;
test_type b = lcg() & 32767;
```

https://ideone.com (ссылки на примеры: [int](https://ideone.com/EwYuK9), [unsigned int](https://ideone.com/ZIwzgh), [long long](https://ideone.com/E9qEv6), [double](https://ideone.com/d3lIdu)), clang 8.0, количество итераций — `800'000'000`, `a == lcg() & mask; b == lcg() & mask`, время в секундах:

```
test_type:    int         unsigned int         long long         double
умножение:    2.22886     2.02724              2.55701           2.05726
или:          2.36976     1.86795              2.30486           1.86942
```

Теперь проверка с помощью умножения работает медленнее. Хотя для типа `int` всё ещё быстрее (Разница во времени не велика, но это не похоже на погрешность при замере времени. Эксперимент проводил несколько раз, проверка через умножение для типа `int` в clang стабильно работает немного быстрее.)

---

В общем, скорость работы сильно зависит от используемого окружения и входных данных. Надёжный ответ на свой вопрос вы получите только после тестов.

---

P.S.

Всё-таки не могу не заметить, что на некоторых входных данных приведённые условия не совсем идентичны. [Взгляните](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755aa6b0b993bab1) на следующий код:

```
unsigned int a = 65536, b = 65536;
cout << a * b << endl; //0, если тип unsigned int - 32-битный
cout << (a == 0 || b == 0) << (a * b == 0) << endl; //01

double x = 0.0, y = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
cout << x * y << endl; //NaN
cout << (x == 0 || y == 0) << (x * y == 0) << endl; //10
```

Comment: А если оптимизацию отключить?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, разница сократилась, но перемножение всё-таки быстрее. gcc с опцией `-O0`: [int](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c4beeb49912a4ff), [double](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6372caa2953df790). Количество итераций правда пришлось уменьшить, т.к. не проходит по времени.

Comment: А если x, y брать random? Время работы умножителя (количество тактов) вообще-то может зависеть от чисел.

Comment: @avp, вы правы, обновил ответ.

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение (обосновать не могу, и вообще - не уверен в нем, так что хотелось бы выслушать специалистов), не играет ли тут основную роль в смысле времени сами переходы?..

Comment: @Harry, да, согласен, неплохо бы выслушать мнение специалистов :)

Comment: А еще явно должны играть роль вероятности равенства нулю a и b - например, если a крайне редко равно 0, а b - часто, то обратный порядок будет явно более быстрым. Словом, тут все очень сильно зависит от конкретных данных...

Comment: @Harry, вообще я думал, что для типа `int` компиляторы будут генерировать одинаковый код, но нет. Да ещё и способ с умножением иногда оказывается быстрее. Как-то это контринтуитивно. Хорошо бы увидеть не просто предположения/сферические замеры производительности в вакууме, а подробное объяснение наблюдаемого поведения. Но тут я не специалист. Кстати, вопрос про [отличия `CMP` от `TEST`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/135230) задавался здесь. В ответах пишут `TEST ` вроде как быстрее.

Comment: Попробовал с random код для `int` и `unsigned int` на своем g++ -O3, Linux Mint, AMD Ryzen 5 3400G. Запустил каждую из 4-х раз по 10. С учетом разброса результатов разницы не заметил. (Уже интересно, да, тут думать надо)

Answer (score 7):

скорее всего первая - будет сделано 2 `cmp` последовательно, а во втором случае все таки надо делать `mul`, хотя все равно это все однотиковые операции

но компиляторы сейчас умные, они и первый и второй вариант превратят во что-то одинаковое, как мне кажется

у меня студия сделала следующее (на максимальной оптимизации):

первый вариант:

```
00007FF7210D5B6C  cmp         dword ptr [rbp+0C0h],0  
00007FF7210D5B73  je          main+6Eh (07FF7210D5B7Eh)  
00007FF7210D5B75  cmp         dword ptr [rbp+0C4h],0  
00007FF7210D5B7C  jne         main+81h (07FF7210D5B91h)
```

второй вариант

```
00007FF6DC065B6C  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+0C0h]  
00007FF6DC065B72  imul        eax,dword ptr [rbp+0C4h]  
00007FF6DC065B79  test        eax,eax  
00007FF6DC065B7B  jne         main+80h (07FF6DC065B90h)
```

видать такой код вообще без разницы как делать :)

протестировал на таком коде (чтобы компилятор чего-то не соптимизировал лишнего):

```
int x, y;
std::cin >> x;
std::cin >> y;

if (x * y == 0)
    std::cout << "r";
```

**P.S.**

как по мне - это скорее всего экономия на спичках и лучше оставить первый вариант как более понятный

Comment: А если поменять int на unsigned, второй вариант ухудшится? Хотя стоп, там же и так `imul`...