# Как компилятор с++ выполняет неявные действия с кодом?

Tags: c++

Есть код по типу:

```
if (1)
   cout << 1;
```

Т.к. 1 - `int`, то оно неявно конвертируется в `bool`. Но у меня вопрос, как происходит эта неявная конвертация? Например во время компиляции компилятор сам допишет туда `(bool)1` или как-то иначе?

Comment: 0 считается false не ноль true. И всё. В данном случае скобки автоматически преобразуют выражение к bool. В данном случа 1 это литерал и он будет оптимизирован (в вечный true, т.е. if уйдёт, ветки не будет, но думаю первым предложением я верно ответил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой код, конечно, будет оптимизирован. Но можно попробовать скомпилировать без оптимизации и посмотреть результат в ассемблере.

Рассмотрим [код](https://godbolt.org/z/sqYKE9M8s):

```
int a = 1;
if (a)
    std::cout << 1;
```

GCC с опцией `-O0` генерирует такой ассемблер:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
je      .L2
mov     esi, 1
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
.L2:
```

За сравнение отвечают первые 3 строки. Сначала идёт команда `mov`, которая записывает в память число для сравнения. Далее, выполняется команда `cmp`. Она вычитает из нашей единицы число 0. Это не бессмысленное действие, потому что при этом выставляются специальные флаги, по которым можно узнать, как относятся друг с другом сравниваемые числа (больше, меньше или равны). Команда `je` перенаправляет выполнение кода на участок, который следует после тела оператора `if`, если сравниваемые числа были равны. Мы знаем, что 1 > 0, поэтому этого не произойдёт, но эта оптимизация не была произведена.

Тут надо понимать, что машинные команды ничего не знают о типе `bool`. И вообще о типах. Все сравнения происходят в ассемблере подобным образом в целых числах. Есть ещё похожая по назначению команда [test](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/135243/235436).

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, но хотелось бы еще прояснить. Если мы находимся в теле описания класса и допустим в каком либо методе мы присваиваем какое-либо значение, некоторому полю этого класса - `int MyClass::abc(){ a = 1; }`, насколько я знаю это  будет эквивалентно следующему - `int MyClass::abc(){ this->a = 1; }`. Так вот, у меня вопрос этот самый `this->` компилятор как будто припишет к коду, или он прост сгенерирует ассемблерный код, как будто там, что то было?

Comment: Ассемблер ничего не знает про C++. Ни про this, ни про объекты. И даже про переменные. На этапе генерации машинного кода уже нет синтаксиса C++. С точки зрения стандарта C++ приведëнные примеры эквивалентны по поведению. Компилятор сгенерирует такой машинный код, который будет соответствовать стандарту. Т.е. будет выполнять то, что вы написали в программе.

Comment: Он не припишет, а просто выяснит, какое `a` есть в области видимости, и если оно единственное и подходит по типу - просто скомпилирует этот код...